# Raid 10 KO on M5110, cannot mount with mdadm

Tags: raid, mdadm

I'm experiencing a terrible fault of my raid 10 made of 4 disks of 4TB connected to a serveraid M5110 card. The VD got degraded and no way to restore it with MegaRaid SW, so I disconnected disks from the serveraid card and got on physical sata ports on mainboard to run `mdadm`.

The results:

```
# mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sde is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sde as it reports /dev/sdb as failed
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 0 of /dev/md0
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md0 as 2 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: Container /dev/md0 has been assembled with 1 drive (out of 2)
```

---

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
          Magic : de11de11
        Version : 01.00.00
Controller GUID : 49424D20:20202020:53563330:32313930:38300000:3A62653A
                  (IBM     SV30219080)
 Container GUID : 49424D20:20202020:1000005B:1014040B:46AF0993:B423E95D
                  (IBM      07/30/17 12:06:11)
            Seq : 000000b1
  Redundant hdr : yes
  Virtual Disks : 1

      VD GUID[0] : 49424D20:20202020:1000005B:1014040B:46AF0994:16E1A7A7
                  (IBM      07/30/17 12:06:12)
         unit[0] : 0
        state[0] : Failed, Not Consistent
   init state[0] : Not Initialised
       access[0] : Read/Write
         Name[0] : VD_RAID10
 Raid Devices[0] : 2 (0@0K 1@0K)
   Chunk Size[0] : 128 sectors
   Raid Level[0] : RAID1
  Secondary Position[0] : 1 of 2
  Secondary Level[0] : Striped
  Device Size[0] : 3906469888
   Array Size[0] : 7812939776

 Physical Disks : 63
      Number    RefNo      Size       Device      Type/State
         0    a899eb71  3906469888K /dev/sdc        active/Offline, Failed
         1    28548427  3906469888K /dev/sdb        active/Online
         2    28548427  3906469888K /dev/sdb        active/Online
         3    28548427  3906469888K /dev/sdb        active/Online
 Physical disks not in metadata!:
   41d13ecd /dev/sdd
```

---

```
# mount /dev/md0 /mnt/usb/
mount: /mnt/usb: can't read superblock on /dev/md0.
```

No way to mount `md0`?

Comment: Are you sure mdadm can even understand lsi raid10 semantics? IIRC mdadm uses it's own raid10 level (not using nested raid at all). Can you simply replace the lsi card with another to test if the problem is in the disks or the card? did you try storcli or megacli commands to check status of cards and vd?

Comment: You should add the output of `mdadm --examine` for each of the drives, too.

Answer (score 0):

This error message seems to belong to RAID-5; in any case it does not make sense for RAID-10.

It may be a good idea to create a small copy-on-write device for each of the disks and use `dmsetup` to set up a snapshot for each. That way you can make tests with the snapshot devices, write to them and easily throw away the changes.

I suggest that you recreate the MD metadata on the disks because the current metadata is obviously misunderstood by `mdadm`.

Copy (e.g. with `dd`) a sector from the three working disks in order to determine which are the RAID-1 pair. Then set up a new RAID-1 with these disks (i.e. their snapshot devices). Mind using the correct offset and metadata version. Do the same with the third drive i.e. set up a degraded RAID-1 with it.

Use `mdadm --build ... --readonly` to create a non-persistent RAID-0 (Mind the correct chunk size!) from the two RAID-1 arrays. Check whether you see a filesystem on the resulting device. If not then delete the new array and change the order of the lower arrays.